# SMTP server problems swift mailer

Tags: yii2

i am using yii2 frame work and i am implementing swift mailer in my web.php file.it's working fine.

my config code:

```
    'mailer' => [
         'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
         'useFileTransport'=>false,
         'transport' => [
             'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
   ``          'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
             'username' => 'testdemomail32@gmail.com',
             'password' => 'TECHEDGE',
             'port' => '465',
             'encryption' => 'ssl',
         ],
     ],
```

but i got problem in when i am implementing same thing in server  side i got response in below:

Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 k8sm2888892qke.45 - gsmtp

any help thanks..

Answer (score 0):

configure swift mailer like below:

```
 'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
           'useFileTransport' => false,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
        //comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'testdemomail32@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'TECHEDGE',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
                        ],
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
        ],
```

go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps  and turn on Access for less secure apps

Comment: i am using above code but i got  response in Invalid path alias: @common/mail.

Comment: ok you can remove that line  if you not using templates.  'viewPath' => '@common/mail',

Comment: in localhost it's worjking fine.but in server side there is no email lesssecureapp is trun on.

Comment: but how to enable lesssecureapps in server

Comment: in your server using this same configuration for smtp? lesssecureapps using gmail settings.first you log in your mail which used for smtp and enable lesssecureapps.

Comment: i m did same thing to enable lesssecureapp. evering thing is working fime in local host.

Comment: in server side i face same problem